# Flutter appbundle version code error. Version code 20220304 has already been used. Try another version code

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build, android-app-bundle

I try build new release for google play, so I change version at file pubspec.yaml from `0.1.1+20220304` to `0.1.4+20220307`, but after uploading, GPlay console return error: `Version code 20220304 has already been used. Try another version code.`
I do not have hardcoded number `20220304` anywhere.
I use app version straight from pubspec.yaml: `version: 0.1.4+20220307`
Why during build tools get old app version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to remove `build` folder from project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

run `flutter clean` before building your apk/bundle